# Leaflet + Turf strange squareGrid behaviour

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, gis, turfjs

After a week of tests, and researches I've decided to "give up" and ask you guys for some help.

What I'm trying to accomplish is fairly easy.

- Take the world map and split it in 4 quadrants (done)
- Take each quadrant, and using **turf** calculate how many squares of N units are contained.

Everything works fine with the 2 first quadrants: A (red), B (green)

[image]

In fact, if I then try to fill the first two quadrants with squares using **turf** the result is correct:

[image]

The problem is that when trying to replicate the same logic on the squares below, **turf** returns 0 squares...

The code used to create the 4 quadrants with **Leaflet** is the following:

```
const quadrantA = L.rectangle(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(90, -180), L.latLng(0, 0)), { weight: 1, fillColor: 'red', color: 'red' });
const quadrantB = L.rectangle(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(90, 0), L.latLng(0, +180)), { weight: 1, fillColor: 'green', color: 'green' });
const quadrantC = L.rectangle(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(0, -180), L.latLng(-90, 0)), { weight: 1, fillColor: 'blue', color: 'blue' });
const quadrantD = L.rectangle(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(0, 0), L.latLng(-90, 180)), { weight: 1, fillColor: 'yellow', color: 'yellow' });

quadrantA.addTo(this.map);
quadrantB.addTo(this.map);
quadrantC.addTo(this.map);
quadrantD.addTo(this.map);
```

Meanwhile the code used to calculate the squares in each quadrant with **turf** is the following:

```
const QGrid_A = turf.squareGrid(turf.bbox(quadrantA.toGeoJSON()), 500, { units: 'kilometers' });
const QGrid_B = turf.squareGrid(turf.bbox(quadrantB.toGeoJSON()), 500, { units: 'kilometers' });
const QGrid_C = turf.squareGrid(turf.bbox(quadrantC.toGeoJSON()), 500, { units: 'kilometers' });
const QGrid_D = turf.squareGrid(turf.bbox(quadrantD.toGeoJSON()), 500, { units: 'kilometers' });
```

Problem is, that the "second round" of calculations returns always 0 features for the quadrants C and D.

QGrid_A features: 800

QGrid_B features: 800

QGrid_C features: 0

QGrid_D features: 0

I've also read about that **Leaflet** reverses the standard GeoJSON coordinates positions, by using [LAT,LON] instead of [LON,LAT], so I've also tried to reverse the result of the **Leaflet** generated GeoJSONs by doing a `reverse` on the coordinates array, but still nothing.

I wonder where am I wrong here? Is it a problem of "looped" coordinates? Is it a problem due to a falsy conversion between Leaflet and Turf? Is it me dumb? Please help me guys.

Comment: Did you resolved the issue? If yes, you can share your experience

Comment: Hey @Travnikov I've just posted my solution. Hope it helps. If you need any more details just ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

## My solution

At the end of the day, I've adopted another strategy. Pretty simple tbh. 
I've created a polygon which is the "area to map". This polygon then is split in several sub-squares polygons. Each square then can be used as an individual "tile". 
Using `@turf/square-grid` and `@turf/bbox` was to achieve this was pretty easy,
the code for this is all incapsulated in 2 functions:

```
export interface ISplitAreaInSubareasConf {
    squareCellSide?: number;
    units?: `meters` | `kilometers`;
}

private splitAreaToMapInSubAreas(areaToMap: Polygon, opts?: ISplitAreaInSubareasConf): BBox[] {
    const units = opts && opts.units ? opts.units : this.SQUARE_UNIT;
    const side = opts && opts.squareCellSide ? opts.squareCellSide : this.SQUARE_CELL_SIDE_IN_KM;

    const grid = turfSquareGrid.default(this.getAreaToMapBBox(areaToMap), side, {units, mask: areaToMap});

    return grid.features.map(feat => this.getAreaToMapBBox(feat.geometry));
}

private getAreaToMapBBox(areaToMap: Polygon) {
    return bbox.default(areaToMap);
}
```